# One View with multi-ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have one Silverlight page, its name is MySampleView. This page will function differently base on user's role, for example, if user role A open this page it will get data from table A but if user role B open this page it will get data from table B.

I want to know is it good to have only one View and 2 ViewModels in this case. If so, what is a proper way to set datacontext? (Currently I set page's DataContext inside xaml which is not support to switch 2 viewmodels for 1 view.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use one ViewModel but change Model layer so you will be able to pass user-role to Model and get data from correspondent table. if the user-role is not the info you want to pass to Model it's OK to conver it to a flag/enum or other type which will be acceptable at Model layer.